# Map inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get all my departments from  the api, then map the object array into a simple array with only one fields values so I can populate a drop down list with those values. I got my code to work and I have this array but i don't know how to transfer it to my div. One idea I came up with is doing the map as I get the values in componentDidMount, but I don't know how to write that.

My componentDidMount:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        userService.getAllDepartments()
        .then(b => {
            this.setState({departments: b})
            });
        }
```

My code that I put inside render() that maps the new array that I need

```
    const objArray = this.state.departments;
    if (objArray !== null){
    let result = objArray.map(a => a.id);
    console.log(result[0])
    }
```

How can I fuse these 2 together so that everything happens in componentDidMount and I can retrieve the new array from my this.state?

Comment: `this.setState({departments: b.map(a => a.id)})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to map the response to an array of department ids you can do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  userService.getAllDepartments()
    .then(result => {
      this.setState({
        departments: result.map(({ id }) => id),
      })
    });
}
```